# Bootstrap 3.4.1 sanitizer: allow progress-bar inside a popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3.4.1 and 4.3.1 now comes with a [sanitizer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#js-sanitizer) to perform XSS prevention.
I'm trying to allow all the necessary attributes to render a progress bar inside the popover of an AdminLTE based on bootstrap 3.4.1.
With `.popover({sanitize: false});` everything works as expected:

[image: working example]

With a custom sanitizer whitelist, as specified on the bootstrap docs, the progress bar is't displayed:

[image: the problem]

This is the custom whitelist:

```js
       var myDefaultWhiteList = $.fn.popover.Constructor.DEFAULTS.whiteList;
        myDefaultWhiteList.div = ['role', 'aria-valuenow', 'aria-valuemin', 'aria-valuemax'];
        myDefaultWhiteList.span = ['class'];
        myDefaultWhiteList.table = ['class'];
        myDefaultWhiteList.tbody = [];
        myDefaultWhiteList.tr = [];
        myDefaultWhiteList.td = ['colspan'];

        console.log(myDefaultWhiteList);

        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                whiteList: myDefaultWhiteList
            });
        });
```

And this is the content of my popover:

```html
<div class="progress progress-sm active">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar"
         aria-valuenow="6" aria-valuemin="0"
         aria-valuemax="10"
         style="width: 60%">
        <span class="sr-only">6/10</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="no-padding">
    <table class="table table-condensed therapy-popover-table">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Protocollo N°</td>
            <td>837-2019PC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Codice prescrizione</td>
            <td>93xxxx1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Prescrizione</td>
            <td><small>IDROCHINESITERAPIA INDIVIDUALE (9xxxx1) (30')</small></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data evento lesivo</td>
            <td>10/09/2019</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data prescrizione</td>
            <td>10/09/2019</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Priorità</td>
            <td>Breve</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tipo prestazione</td>
            <td>Privato</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><a href="/prescription/update/2602"><i class="fa fa-share-square"></i> Vai alla prescrizione</a></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Does anyone experienced a problem with bootstrap sanitizer and custom whitelist?
In my, everything works (tables, colspan attributes, etc...) except the progress bar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shit. I forgot the `style` attribute.

So the right role is:

```js
myDefaultWhiteList.div = ['style'];
```

because `'role', 'aria-valuenow', 'aria-valuemin', 'aria-valuemax'` are already defined in the default whitelist.