# How to add tag table in Bootstrap Tooltip

Tags: bootstrap-4, tooltip

I initialize objects as follows

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    title: function () {
        return '<u>text1</u><table class="table"><tr><td>text2</td></tr></table>';
    }
});
```

But I only see the `text1`.
Is it possible to insert a table into a tooltip?

Answer (score 3):

I found an [issue on Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30764) stating that [Bootstrap's sanitizer](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer) causes this problem.

What you need to do is to allow all elements that are used for your table in a whitelist (also `tbody`, which is not defined by your code, but it seems like you need it). Also have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135466/bootstrap-3-4-1-sanitizer-allow-progress-bar-inside-a-popover), where it is done for a popover. Afterwards, you can use this custom whitelist in your `tooltip` options again.

I have created a [running fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mrwtx6h/17/):

```js
var myDefaultWhiteList = $.fn.tooltip.Constructor.Default.whiteList;
myDefaultWhiteList.table = ['class'];
myDefaultWhiteList.tbody = [];
myDefaultWhiteList.tr = [];
myDefaultWhiteList.td = [];

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
  container: 'body',
  html: true,
  whiteList: myDefaultWhiteList,
  title: function () { return '<u>text1</u><table class="table text-light"><tr><td>text2</td></tr></table>'; }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="ml-5 mt-5 btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip">
  Test
</button>
```

As you might notice, this is a behavior that is not suggested by Bootstrap. I recommend to use [Bootstrap's popovers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/popovers/) for larger contents such as tables.

Good luck!

Comment: I have the same issue. With your solution, the tooltip now contains the table but shows the source code, not an html table. It is as if html were set to false although I have data-html="true" in the actual tooltip. Just to be sure, in the jquery call to the tooltip function I also added it so I have 2 elements: "html: true,  whiteList: myDefaultWhiteList" but the same result. Any idea why I am not seeing the table in html?

Comment: Just solved it. The problem was that I had included the bootstrap.min.js with the "async" property. Removing "async" solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the content of the tooltip is added to the title attribute of the element that you are applying the tooltip on.  To break it down, essentially what you're trying to do is...

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" title="<u>text1</u><table class="table"><tr><td>text2</td></tr></table>">
Foo
</div>

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

If you want to include information in a table as a tooltip, I think you'd have to create an element containing the table, position it correctly near the element you want to hover over & use the $.hover to show and hide the element.  Something similar to

```js
$('#hoverTest').hover(function(){
  $('#customTooltip').removeClass('hideme');
}, function(){
  $('#customTooltip').addClass('hideme');
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.hideme{
  display:none
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hoverTest">Hover here</div>
<div id="customTooltip" class="hideme">
  <table>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell1</td>
      <td>Cell2</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest trick with jquery. http://jsfiddle.net/b80tn4hx/3/

```js
$('a').hover(function(ev){
    $('.tablediv').stop(true,true).fadeIn(); 
},function(ev){
    $('.tablediv').stop(true,true).fadeOut();
}).mousemove(function(ev){
    $('.tablediv').css({left:ev.layerX+10,top:ev.layerY+10});
});
```

```css
.container{
  padding: 15px;
}
.tablediv{
   display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background: #999;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
td{
   border:1px solid #777;   
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">test</a>
  <div class="tablediv">
    <table>
        <tr><td>asdf</td><td>gsdi</td></tr>
        <tr><td>asdf</td><td>gsdi</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the *whiteList* now is an **allowList** and is not so "hidden".

There is an example of the javascript code necessary to use table, tbody, td and etc. inside the title of the tooltip.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer

I hope this helps.